# csv.writerow writes to columns not rows

Tags: python

I have a Python test file which is a list of strings that I am trying to export into a csv file so that each word in the string is in a single column in the csv file.  However my code places each word into a separate column within a single row.  I have read others comments regarding similar issues on this site and they suggested changing the syntax to `wr.writerows([csv_data])`.  This modification does not work on the code below.  I am a beginner at Python so would  greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this.

```
testfile=['free', 'great', 'congratulations', 'great', 'kind', 'freedom']

import csv
with open("pos_words_pre.csv",'w') as resultFile_pos_pre:
    wr_pos_pre = csv.writer(resultFile_pos_pre)
    wr_pos_pre.writerow(testfile)
```

Thank you very much for the help

EDIT: The code above will place all the words in a csv file in the same row such as: 
    free, great, congratulations, great, kind, freedom

But I'm trying to create a file that has each entry in the same column but a separate row such as:

```
free
great
congratulations
great
kind
freedom
```

I though that writerow will write each entry into a separate row in an excel csv file rather than the same row.  Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Please show what you want the output file to look like.

Comment: This would output the line: ``free,great,congratulations,great,kind,freedom``, so I don't understand the problem.

Comment: "However my code places each word into a separate column within a single row." - well, yeah. That's what it means to write a row, which is exactly what you should expect from a method called `writerow`.

Comment: `writerow()` write one **row** of data passed to it. You're passing it `testfile` which is a list of six things and it assumes they all go on the same line. Use `writerows()` instead—note the "s" at the end.

Comment: Why are you using `csv.writer` if you're just writing one string on each line? It's not a CSV file if there's just one field.

Comment: Barmar, good point.  My goal is to export this list for analysis in R.  Is there a better way to do this rather than csv format?

Answer (score 4):

`writerow` writes a single row. If you want to write multiple rows and use this function then you have to call it separately for each row:

```
import csv
testfile=['free', 'great', 'congratulations', 'great', 'kind', 'freedom']
with open("pos_words_pre.csv",'w') as resultFile_pos_pre:
    wr_pos_pre = csv.writer(resultFile_pos_pre)
    for row in testfile:
        wr_pos_pre.writerow([row])
```

Alternatively you can write many rows at once:

```
with open("pos_words_pre.csv",'w') as resultFile_pos_pre:
    wr_pos_pre = csv.writer(resultFile_pos_pre)
    wr_pos_pre.writerows(([row] for row in testfile))
```

Comment: The answer from user8153 works well aside from the blank row that is placed between each word in the same column.  However if I change the wr_pos_pre = csv.writer(resultFile_pos_pre,lineterminator='\n') then it works perfectly.  Thank you very much for the help.